# How come people say "I'm friends with sb." rather than "I'm a friend with sb."?

Tags: expressions, subject-verb-agreement, singular-vs-plural

How come people say "I'm **friends** with sb." rather than "I'm a friend with sb."?

And there are expressions like "He was **friends** with Jack"...

It's just not grammatical! How can "I" or "he" be "friends"?